# Angular velocity of a cylinder rolling in another cylinder

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm having troubles with the following problem:
Consider a hollow cylinder of radius $2R$ which has a point of its rim fixed in an inertial frame and can rotate about this fixed point. Inside it there's another hollow cylinder with the same mass as the first one but radius $R$. The inner cylinder can roll without slipping inside the outer one. The whole system is subjected to gravity.

I am trying to write the Lagrangian for the system in terms of the angle the center of the outer cylinder makes with the vertical and the angle made with the vertical by the line joining the two centers, but I don't know how to write the angular velocity of the inner cylinder in terms of this two coordinates taking care of the non slipping condition.
Could someone please help me figuring this out?
Thanks

Comment: for the rolling condition the relative velocity at the contact point is zero $2R\dot{\varphi }_{1}=R\dot{\varphi }_{2}$

Answer (score 0):

When you fix the angle $\theta_1$ the center of the outer cylinder makes with the vertical and the angle $\theta_2$ made with the vertical by the line joining the two centers, the movement of the system is not determined. You have to add a third angle $\varphi$ such that the angular velocity of the inner cylinder is $\dot{\varphi}\vec{e_z}$ . The non slipping condition will introduce a relation between these 3 angles.
Hope it can help.